# How do I make A unity2d game playable with a chrome extension

Tags: visual-studio

I know no java or any other language besides c#, so how would I try to make it a popup chrome extension that you can play in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can read this: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/

I'm pretty sure that in Unity, you can build an application as WebGL. You can read this if you want: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html

Then, you can put the code they give you for the WebGL and put it inside the extensions HTML, and then I think it'll work.

Comment: okay, but I do not know how to use it after that

Comment: What do you mean? I think you can just keep the manifest, and after you port it, you can put the HTML file they gave you and turn it into the popup.html in the example.

Comment: actually, is there any way that I can put it on a replit

Comment: First, get the webgl thing. Then put it into a replit. Very simple. For a template, choose the HTML, CSS, JS one, and then put in the code you got.

Comment: so like a website? can you walk me through it because I have no idea how to add the script

Comment: I tried, but it only shows 2 folders, and I dont know how to add it

Comment: What is in the folders?

Comment: Can you open them in your file explorer app and tell me the filenames?

Comment: just one that says a build and another one. can I please have your email? or would you like ot continue here

Comment: Ok never mind. Just delete everything that came in the replit template and put all the files and folders you got from the build and put them in the replit There should be a folder called build, a folder called TemplateData, and an index.html file. move those three things into the replit.

Comment: okay, it shows the player and it is starting to work, but for some reason, when it is about to load i see it say

Comment: Unable to parse Build/webtest.framework.js.br! This can happen if build compression was enabled but web server hosting the content was misconfigured to not serve the file with HTTP Response Header "Content-Encoding: br" present. Check browser Console and Devtools Network tab to debug.

Comment: Can you rebuild your game except this time in the build settings, change the compression format to gzip or disabled. If you need more help, go here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-webgl-build-error-unable-to-parse-build-file-name-framework-js-br.1102759/

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH if you want you can play my game at https://idk.dylansantwani1.repl.co

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Comment: sure, can you help me with a quick question on how to use Input.GetAxisRaw and stuff?

Comment: I think you should ask another question. I'll try to help you.

Comment: I did ask it the link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73561865/how-to-use-getaxisraw-with-2d-movement-beginner-unity thank you