# how to use GetAxisRaw with 2d movement (beginner unity)

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am making a platformer game where you have to dodge spikes, and I tried to use the transform.position method, but it gave too many bugs. With rigidbodies(rb.addforce), it has acceleration, and I saw somewhere that you could use getaxisraw to do it. Is there any way that I could add this to my current script without deviating too much (still being able to use wasd and arrow keys)?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movespeed = 0.01f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public bool isgrounded = true;
    public float jumpheight = 500f;
    public float level = 1;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        rb = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-Vector2.right * movespeed);
            
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && isgrounded || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && isgrounded))
        {

            rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpheight);
            isgrounded = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)||(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.right * movespeed);
           
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "enemy")
        {
            Debug.Log("hio");
            if (level == 1)
            {
                Debug.Log("resetpos");
                transform.position = new Vector3((float)-11.343, (float)-0.49, 0);

            }
        }
    }



    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "ground")
        {
            isgrounded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html, I think that `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` will return `-1` if the user presses in left or a, `0` if the user is not pressing left or right or a or d, and `1` if the user presses right or d. Similarly, this also occurs for `Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")`. I think it will return `-1` if the user wants to go down, `0` if the user is not pressing up or down, and `1` if the user wants to go up.

In `FixedUpdate()`, you can get `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` to get whether they want to move right or left, and `Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")` to get whether they want to move down or up. Then, you can handle it by moving the character appropriately.

For example, you can do this:

```c#
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == -1) 
    {
    // Code to move left
    } 
    else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == 1) {
    // Code to move right
    }

    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") == -1)
    {
    // Code to move down or squat
    }
    else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") == 1)
    {
    // Code to move up or jump
    }
}
```

Please excuse me if I made any C# syntax errors.

Comment: I understand this, but how do I actually use it in a script?

Comment: Like, what would I use to see if they were pressing it?